# checkboxed selected rows from gridview1 to gridview2 ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

As title said it all anyway I have a table is `sql-server` ***products***.

Which  has product id, name,price and cetegory.

what i did is i get data into 1st `GridView` category wise, and what i want is when i checked that particular row or multiple row and click select button it shuld show product name and price in 2nd gridview.

But what its do is it override the next selected item to previously selected item in 2nd gridview and shows onlu one row not multiple selected items.

can anybody help me ??

here is a code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            CheckBox chbox = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;

            if (chbox.Checked == true)
            {
                string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test_T3ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
                string query = "select prod_name,price from products where prod_id = '" + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                GridView2.DataSource = dt;
                GridView2.DataBind();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You appear to be setting a new `DataSource`/`DataBind()` on the same `GridView2` instance each time within the loop... this will do as you say, and leave you with only the last item in the list

Answer (score 0):

You binded the grid too many times.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
List<string> checkedIDs = new List<string>();

 for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {

    CheckBox chbox = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;

    if (chbox.Checked == true)
    {
        checkedIDs.Add("'" + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "'");
    }

}


        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test_T3ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
        string query = "select prod_name,price from products where prod_id in (" + string.Join(",", checkedIDs.ToArray()) + ")";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amiram it works!!! so it means i have to store them in array first, right ?

Comment: Yes, you need to save them first

Comment: but what actually this code did ?? string.Join(",", checkedIDs.ToArray()) ;

Comment: It is converting the list to a string. If you have a list with a, b and c, you'll get "a,b,c". Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx